# Concatenate two dataframes and remove duplicate rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two dataframe and in case of duplication I'd like to consider the row that has the maximum value for a column C
I tried this command :

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).max(level=0)
```

So if two rows have same value for columns A and B, I will just take that row with the maximum value for column C.

Comment: Define `in case of duplication`. How are 2 rows duplicates if they have different 'C' values?

Comment: I would say If two rows have same value for coluns A and B I will just take that row  with the maximum value for column C

Answer (score 2):

You can sort by column C, then drop duplicates by columns A & B:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])\
       .sort_values('C')\
       .drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'], keep='last')
```

Your attempt exhibits a couple of misunderstandings:

1. [`pd.DataFrame.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) is used to calculate maximum values, not to filter a dataframe.
2. The `level` parameter is relevant only for `MultiIndex` dataframes.